# How to use NPM Package Config Variables in Docker commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

I have a `package.json` file with a single `config` variable for the app port:

**package.json**

```
...
"config":{
  "port": "3000"
},
...
```

I also have a `script` defined to run a docker image. Now, I'd like to use the config variable in the command where I run my docker image. From [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#config) I can see how to use npm config variables. So my script becomes:

**package.json** (same one)

```
....
"scripts": {
    "docker:run": "docker run --rm -it -p $npm_package_config_port:$npm_package_config_port my-app:latest"
}
...
```

However, the variable `port` is never interpolated. Instead, I get an error from Docker when running:

`Invalid containerPort: $npm_package_config_port`

**Question**

How do I use a npm variable in my docker command via npm scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on windows? NPM configuration variables use environment variables under the hood.  If so, you might want to try to reference it with %VAR_NAME% (instead of $).  Explanation: https://gist.github.com/bresheske/9afe4392b69fb6fb5f68bdf12e84f748

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this with Node 4.7.3 and npm 2.15.11

package.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo $npm_package_config_port"
  }
}
```

Try running `npm start` and it should output the port 3000.
If it does not work, try the following package.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env"
  }
}
```

This will output all environment variables and you can check if the port variable is available.

I'm not sure but the environment variables support could have been added with a newer node/npm version compared to the one you're using. Paste the output of `node -v` and `npm -v` so that we can check.